# docker privileged container giving storage full error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, systemd, docker-volume

I have a CentOS 7 docker container that has an apache browser running as "systemd service" (Yes it's a privileged container). After a few days, the apache service stops running in the container, and "journalctl -xe" command gives me an error about the full storage at "/run". I didn't mount this volume. This is mounted by docker without my consent. This volume has tmpfs filesystem. When I restart the container "/run" gets cleaned and the error goes away.

Also when volume at /run is full then there's still a lot of space available in the host OS disk. How can I configure the container to auto clear data at "/run" so that it doesn't get full?
Also, I would like to know what kind of data is stored at "/run".

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if systemd created the `/run` mount.  It wants to manage a lot of things – kernel parameters, filesystem mounts, network settings – and I'd avoid it in Docker.  Do you have a [mcve] showing how you built the image, and any hints as to where `/run` came from?  Can you use a lighter-weight init system like systemd, or no init system at all?